# Trying to create a Hyper-V 2012 R2 *Generation 2* VM via WMI calls to the the V2 namepace via Powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi, hyper-v

I am trying to create a Hyper-V 2012 R2 *Generation 2* VM via WMI calls to the the V2 namepace via Powershell.

I know Windows no has a bunch of Hyper-V code inbuilt to Powershell V3, but I am doing some things too so need to write it myself.

It seems pretty straightforward.

I call the defineSystem method, get my VirtualSystemSettingData object and set:

```
$VSSD.ElementName=$VM
$VSSD.VirtualSystemSubtype="Microsoft:Hyper-V:SubType:2"
```

I think call ModifySystemSettings and get no errors.

VirtualSystemSubType does indeed =" Microsoft:Hyper-V:SubType:2" in the object if I read it before the commit, and even though I can verify the value I always seem to create a generation 1 VM. I'm sure I'm doing something silly but I can't spot it.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone happens on this (unlikely as i was being stupid).

I was trying to modify the Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData object after creation, which is fine for things like name etc, but seemingly not for generation (makes sense, i guess).

Spawn a instance of Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData and then pass it to DefineSystem, with the settings you require, and the generation etc.

ModifySystemSettings could probably handle this better, but i was going about it in a funny way, now i know how it works.